# macOS trusts Python whl files, but not tar files

Tags: python, macos, security, pip, shared-libraries

I provide my python c extension as both as a tar file, as well as a whl file.

On macOS, I am surprised that there are no problems installing the wheel for my extension.  When setting PYTHONPATH to my python extension in the tarball, I am immediately met with the dialog about unverified developers.

Could someone please explain why macOS trusts my unsigned python extension, but has no problem if I package it in a wheel file.

Update: This is the error I see after I close the dialog box:

```
>>> import devsim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jsanchez/Downloads/devsim_macos_v2.3.7rc1/lib/devsim/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .devsim_py3 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jsanchez/Downloads/devsim_macos_v2.3.7rc1/lib/devsim/devsim_py3.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/jsanchez/Downloads/devsim_macos_v2.3.7rc1/lib/devsim/devsim_py3.so' (code signature in <ED44BB00-36CF-39A8-8999-8309CBA016E4> '/Users/jsanchez/Downloads/devsim_macos_v2.3.7rc1/lib/devsim/devsim_py3.so' not valid for use in process: library load disallowed by system policy)
```

Could someone please explain why macOS trusts my unsigned python extension, but has no problem if I package it in a wheel file.

Update 2:

From what I can see.  If I download the tgz to my Downloads folder using Chrome, I am getting the error.  If I download the tgz using curl, it works.  I am thinking that Chrome is adding this bad attribute.

[image]

Comment: I'm just guessing but does the method for expanding wheel files propagate quarantine attributes? Try running `ls -l@` on the tar and whl files, and extracted contents of both and see which ones have a "com.apple.quarantine" xattr.

Comment: @starball, thanks for pointing out the importance of images of text.  At that moment, the macOS interface is returning a GUI dialog for a command line driven python script.  I'm not sure what would possess macOS to present a GUI dialog for a failing command line application.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, thanks for the tip.  Both of the files have that attribute.  I have since loaded the whl to pypi, and it installs correctly.  I'm thinking that maybe the python binary is properly signed, and the pip install puts the dynamic libraries in an "appropriate" path with respect to the security requirements.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Please see update 2 above.  I am under the impression that Chrome added whatever attribute is causing my module to be treated as malware.

Comment: @Juan Chrome is not marking it as malware, it's marking it as having come from an untrusted source (i.e. the Internet), and therefore subject to more rigorous checking (which makes it check for a developer's code signature). If anything, the fact that `curl` *doesn't* set the com.apple.quarantine xattr could be considered a bug.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson, I have found an article linked in my answer below that explains how all of this stuff is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @GordonDavisson for his tip concerning the attributes.  It turns out the issue was related to google chrome.  If I download the file from Github using Chrome I get:

```
    com.apple.macl       72 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms        655 
    com.apple.quarantine         57
```

and using curl I get no attributes.

I have lax security permissions in Chrome (no safe browsing), but this still occurs.  I will be sure to look out for this the next time I encounter it.

*Update*

I found this very useful post concerning the current macOS landscape:
https://eclecticlight.co/2021/02/18/code-signing-requirements-for-scripts-and-apps-in-big-sur/